# How to show nested structures in Splunk table

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Let's say I have the following kind of event:

```
{"title":"title1","movieStatistics":[{"country":"US","cast":[{"name":"Actor1","age":30,"languages":["English","Spanish"]},{"name":"Actor2","age":48,"languages":["English","Polish","Spanish"]}]}]}
```

With the following search:
index="index-blabla"  | table "movieStatistics{}.cast{}.languages{}" "movieStatistics{}.cast{}.age"

I obtain this table:

| movieStatistics{}.cast{}.languages{} | movieStatistics{}.cast{}.age |
| --- | --- |
| English Spanish English Polish Spanish | 30 48 |

Which is not easy to exploit as I cannot really associate the "age"  and the "languages" (I know it doesn't make sense, but it is just for the sake of the example).

Could you help me find the appropriate search in order to have a table like the following:

| movieStatistics{}.cast{}.languages{} | movieStatistics{}.cast{}.age |
| --- | --- |
| English Spanish | 30 |
| English Polish Spanish | 48 |

I tried the `mvexpand`, but it looks like it doesn't fit my need.

Comment: Please share the raw, unformatted event.

Comment: @RichG unformatted json event shared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `spath` to parse the `_raw` and get all the stuff broken down, then that is too late to use `mvexpand`.  You need to use `mvexpand` before you break down the content of the array elements:

```
| spath movieStatistics{}.cast{}
| mvexpand movieStatistics{}.cast{}
| spath input=movieStatistics{}.cast{}
```

What that does is `spath` the `movieStatistics{}.cast{}` array and then do the `mvexpand` to separate all the parts of the array and then `spath` the different records to get separate events for each array element.

Here is a run-anywhere example:

```
| makeresults
| eval _raw="{\"title\":\"title1\",\"movieStatistics\":[{\"country\":\"US\",\"cast\":[{\"name\":\"Actor1\",\"age\":30,\"languages\":[\"English\",\"Spanish\"]},{\"name\":\"Actor2\",\"age\":48,\"languages\":[\"English\",\"Polish\",\"Spanish\"]}]}]}"
| spath movieStatistics{}.cast{}
| mvexpand movieStatistics{}.cast{}
| spath input=movieStatistics{}.cast{}
| fields - _raw _time movieStatistics{}.cast{}
| table *
```

Comment: the spath + mvexpand worked as a charm, thanks @JerryJaremiah